# Add an open "other" textfield to a checkbox list and set the value to empty?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, hidden

I have created a multi selectable checkbox list and i like to add an open "other" textfield as last option.

```
$("input[name='brands[]']").click(function() {
    if( $(this).val()=='other') {
        $("#other-brands").toggle();
    }
});
```

I have done this by adding a textfield with id 'other-brands" to hidden. If the checkbox 'other' is seleceted the textfield is show. When deselected the textfield is hidden again.

But how do set the value of textfield #other-brands to empty again.

regards

Comment: `$("#other-brands").val("")`?

Comment: will give it a try looks ok, tx

Comment: Oh and how do i set unchecked all checkboxes if hidden?

Comment: `$("input[name='brands[]']:checked").attr("checked",false);` look at the jquery docs http://api.jquery.com/ you will find information about all of the jquery functions there